# UDP port arduino increment after packet sent

Tags: sockets, networking, arduino, udp, ethernet

I'm working on a code to communicate two arduinos, one with ethernet shield and another with an ENC28J60 ethernet module. I'm not a newbie in arduino neither an wise/expert yet. But i'm a complete -and less than a- newbie in UDP communication.

Here is the question: my code works fine, it sends and receives UDP packets from one to another and viceversa. But after every packet is sent, it increment in one the "Udp.remotePort" value (that viewing from the "udp-reader" side). It starts from 1024 up to ~32000 (and starts over after reach the highest value). I have researched about UDP and i understand that the first 0-1023 are reserved for specifics services p.e. 80 http, 21 ftp. But i think it should not be incremented after every send. Or it should?

I don't paste the code because as i said it works OK. I just would like to know what could be wrong from your experience.

The sentence i'm using to write the packets is:

```
udp.beginPacket(IPAddress([ip address]), [port no]);
```

The libraries i'm using:

```
UIPEthernet.h https://github.com/UIPEthernet/UIPEthernet for ENC28J60
```

Ethernet.h for ethernet shield

EDIT: This is the code of the UDP sender (ENC28J60). Basically is the example code of the library as i said it works correctly in terms of communication. I only changed the IPs: 192.168.1.50 which is the UDP sender and 192.168.1.51 which is the UDP destination.

```
#include <UIPEthernet.h>

EthernetUDP udp;
unsigned long next;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  uint8_t mac[6] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05};

  Ethernet.begin(mac,IPAddress(192,168,1,51));
// Also i used: Ethernet.begin(mac,IPAddress(192,168,1,51), 5000); 
// with the same result

  next = millis()+2000;
}

void loop() {

  int success;
  int len = 0;

  if (((signed long)(millis()-next))>0)
    {
      do
        {
          success = udp.beginPacket(IPAddress(192,168,1,50),5000);
          Serial.print("beginPacket: ");
          Serial.println(success ? "success" : "failed");
          //beginPacket fails if remote ethaddr is unknown. In this case an
          //arp-request is send out first and beginPacket succeeds as soon
          //the arp-response is received.
        }
      while (!success && ((signed long)(millis()-next))<0);
      if (!success )
        goto stop;

      success = udp.write("hello world&from&arduino");

      Serial.print("bytes written: ");
      Serial.println(success);

      success = udp.endPacket();

      Serial.print("endPacket: ");
      Serial.println(success ? "success" : "failed");

      do
        {
          //check for new udp-packet:
          success = udp.parsePacket();
        }
      while (!success && ((signed long)(millis()-next))<0);
      if (!success )
        goto stop;

      Serial.print("received: '");
      do
        {
          int c = udp.read();
          Serial.write(c);
          len++;
        }
      while ((success = udp.available())>0);
      Serial.print("', ");
      Serial.print(len);
      Serial.println(" bytes");

      //finish reading this packet:
      udp.flush();

      stop:
      udp.stop();
      next = millis()+2000;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: This is a capture of testing with SocketTest [listening on port 5000, and after a packet received, the next one arrives with the remote port incremented on 1 each time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP4MB.jpg)

Comment: If the code works 100% OK you don't have a question. If you have a question you have to post the code.

Comment: OK, i ' ve posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

You must be creating a new UDP socket per sent datagram. Don't do that. Use the same one for the life of the application.

Comment: I don't know how to avoid that, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @charly989, do you reopen a file each time you write to it during your application life? No, that would be silly and slow. Open the socket during your application setup, use it during the application loop, and close it when the application is done.

Comment: OK, good analogy i understand your point (and i will apply it). However i still don't know why in this particular code the port increments on 1 after each packet sent. Please check the uploaded img. (EDIT 2).

Comment: @charly989 I don't know anything about the API you are using but this is undoubtedly what it is doing. Every new socket will get a new port. There is no way for an existing socket to change its port, so there is no other explanation.